# Flutter - NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'focusScopeNode' was called on null

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I am having the following error while trying to pass `List` from one screen to another. The data is being passed from the `async` function. I need to open the other Screen based on the data fetched from the database.
The answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58498899/11913050) didn't work for me.
here is the error.

```
: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The 
getter 'focusScopeNode' was called on null.
E/flutter (26425): Receiver: null    
E/flutter (26425): Tried calling: focusScopeNode
E/flutter (26425): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (26425): #1      Route.didPush.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:139:17)
```

**Code in async function**

```
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    return ParentHome(childList);
```

**ParentHome Screen**

```
      class ParentHome extends StatefulWidget {
  List childDataList;

  ParentHome(this.childDataList);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ParentHomeWidget();
    }
   }
class ParentHomeWidget extends State<ParentHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widget.childDataList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
                title: Text(widget.childDataList[index]['title']),
              )),
    ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am not finding any help regarding this. Please help me figure this out. I am a newbie in Flutter yet. Thanks

**Flutter Doctor Output**

> Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
>       • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /home/jamshaid/Documents/flutter_linux_v1.9.1+hotfix.4-stable/flutter
>       • Framework revision 27321ebbad (6 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
>       • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
>       • Dart version 2.7.0
>   **complete sync function**

```
Future<void> requestLogin(String userType) async {
/*
final response =
    await http.get('http://10.0.2.2/php_to_flutter/login_validation.php');*/
String databaseAddress = "";

switch (userType) {
  case "Student":
    databaseAddress = AppUtils.studentLoginLink;
    break;
  case "Parent":
    databaseAddress = AppUtils.parentLoginLink;

    break;
  case "Teacher":
    databaseAddress = AppUtils.teacherLoginLink;
    break;
}

    final response = await http
    .post(databaseAddress, body: {"email": email, "password": password});
String responseBody = response.body;

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  switch (userType) {
    case "Student":
      print("Registration # $responseBody");
      break;
    case "Parent":
      List childList = responseBody.split(",");
      //child list needs to be separated by :
      /*Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ParentHome(childList)));
      */
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return ParentHome(childList);
      }));
      //Navigator.pop(context);

      print("Child List= $responseBody");
      break;
    case "Teacher":
      print("Teacher id= $responseBody");
      break;
  }
  form_key.currentState.reset();
  //dismissing progress dialog
  Navigator.pop(context);
  Toast.show("Login Successful", context,
      duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.CENTER);
 } else {
   Navigator.pop(context);
  print(databaseAddress);

  Toast.show("Error: " + response.statusCode.toString(), context,
      duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.CENTER);

  print('error' + response.body);
  print(response.statusCode);
 }
 }
```

**async caller code**
Async function is being called in `onPressed` of a `RaisedButton`.

```
Widget studentLoginButton() {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (form_key.currentState.validate()) {
          form_key.currentState.save();
          //  pr.show();
          AppUtils.showProgressDialog(context, "Loggin in...");
          requestLogin("Student");
          form_key.currentState.reset();

          //pr.dismiss();
        }

        // form_key.currentState.reset();
      },
      child: Text('S Login'),
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the full async function as well as where it is being called? Also, what version of Flutter are you using for this app? You can run  `flutter doctor` to get this information.

Comment: sure. lemme just post this

Comment: @JacobMcGowan please have a look at the question now. I have added the required code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have another `Navigator.pop(context);` after the switch block. Try removing that one as well or setting a `default` case if the intention was to navigate back if none of cases match.

```
switch (userType) {
    case "Student":
      print("Registration # $responseBody");
      break;
    case "Parent":
      List childList = responseBody.split(",");
      //child list needs to be separated by :
      /*Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ParentHome(childList)));
      */
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return ParentHome(childList);
      }));
      //Navigator.pop(context);

      print("Child List= $responseBody");
      break;
    case "Teacher":
      print("Teacher id= $responseBody");
      break;
  }
  form_key.currentState.reset();
  //dismissing progress dialog
  //Navigator.pop(context);
  Toast.show("Login Successful", context,
      duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.CENTER);
```

or

```
switch (userType) {
    case "Student":
      print("Registration # $responseBody");
      break;
    case "Parent":
      List childList = responseBody.split(",");
      //child list needs to be separated by :
      /*Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ParentHome(childList)));
      */
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return ParentHome(childList);
      }));
      //Navigator.pop(context);

      print("Child List= $responseBody");
      break;
    case "Teacher":
      print("Teacher id= $responseBody");
      break;
    default:
      form_key.currentState.reset();
      //dismissing progress dialog
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Toast.show("Login Successful", context,
        duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.CENTER);
  }
```

Comment: your first suggestion worked which was to remove the pop after the switch block. Would you please explain why did it happen with that pop and didn't without it? Thanks

Comment: In this case you can think of the navigation routes as a list, or a stack, where the last route is the current one that is being viewed. `push` adds a new route to the to the end and navigates there while `pop` removes the last route navigating back to the previous one. Routing does not happen immediately but when you `push` or `pop`. Instead, these functions start the process asynchronously. So when you call `push` then `pop` immediately after each other, it causes this issue.

Comment: It works on the basis of a Stack. Thanks for letting explaining.